# How to create multiple HighCharts.js

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I try to create multiple of chart with HighCharts.js on ionic3 and my code like this

```
 var mm = [];
      this.listsensor.forEach((element, index) => {
        mm[index] = HighCharts.chart(element, {
          .......
        });

      });
```

but the result is

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13
```

Comment: Your `element` does not exist. You need to create a `div` to house each highchart instance. That is error 13.

Comment: but this.listsensor is had data like this  ["OP/S1/D","OP/S1/D",....]

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean in your comment. Every chart needs HTML `<div>` to render. So your list should be an array of HTML `<div>` objects (not an array of Strings).